# How to convert a .svg to a 3D Model?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to achieve the embossed effect seen in the attached image. I have made an svg file and imported it into Blender. I am not sure how to proceed to get that emboss effect. Do I have to follow some other steps? I don't know I'm going into the right direction [image: desired result]

You can get the [svg file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZWmxSMjZFSzVzQWM)

Comment: Can you tell me how to achieve that model

Comment: @atek unfortunately there's no automated (press of a button) way to give that 2d shape the 3d body seen in this image. (at least not in Blender). http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2016/10/10/microsoft-paint-revamp/ microsoft's new version of Paint will be have such feature soon. until then you will have to do some manual 3d modelling.

Answer (score 3):

since you didn't tell the detail, I will try to answer in the beginning.

1. first you need to import your svg file

   File > Import > Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
2. its look like your svg is too small, goto edit mode and scale it up

   press tab, then 's' to scale it up. remember to do it in edit mode.
3. goto the curve panel then increase the bevel depth value
   [image: Increase bevel depth value]

this method will not get the very similar result to your reference image. if you want to get a great result you need to modelling it manually.

Answer (score -2):

Within Blender, go to File | User Preferences.

[image]

Within the User Preferences Tab, click on the Add-Ons Tab.
[image]

Within the search box, type "SVG". You should see the Import-Export SVG add-on as an option. Click the small check box at the top left corner of the add on, and then  click "Save User Settings" at the bottom of the add-ons section.

You can then close the User Preferences panel... but remember to save the user settings before doing so.

Now go to File | Import | Scalable Vector Graphics:

[image]

Blender will import your svg.... as you can see in my jpg.

Should if I can help.

Comment: he already imported the svg..